# Mapbox map is not appearing in my html page

Tags: javascript, angular, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have ran into a problem while making a store locator.  The api works fine but my map does not load for some reason. I've been trying to make the map appear in various ways but nothing works. I have checked if it is under the background, it is not. Any help is appreciated! Using Google Chrome on Windows 10.My current HTML code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.12.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.12.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  </head>
<body>
<div class="container my-3">
    <h1 class="display-4 text-center">
      <i class="fas fa-map-marked mr-4"></i>Store Locator
    </h1>
    <a (click)="toAdd();" class="btn btn-success mb-4">Add Store</a>
    <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 500px; border-radius: 5px;"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="js/map.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My map.js script:

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoidG9tYWp1bGkiLCJhIjoiY2tlZWQxYzVnMTBrdzMxbXRmdW5sYW1jeiJ9.Iwm-KsArvbOAzb1ddDJyWQ';

const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
  zoom: 9,
  center: [-71.157895, 42.707741]
  });
```

File setup: [directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYV2L.jpg)
Picture of where map should be: [place where map should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxz1w.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of things to investigate here:

Is the `div` element getting created where you expect? Set its background to yellow to see.

Is your Javascript actually getting executed? Put an alert in.

Are the Mapbox libraries getting loaded? Check the network tab.

Is the map element getting initialised? Log the value of `map` after you create it.

Any of those things could be going wrong.

I'm also suspicious of this line:

> <a (click)="toAdd();" class="btn btn-success mb-4">Add Store

That `(click)` is not standard HTML. I don't know if that's the cause of your problem though.